# No route matches [POST] in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On submitting the forms I get a routing error

```
resources :sellers do
    resources :seller_profiles
end
```

```
<%= form_for seller_seller_profiles_path do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :other_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :other_name %>
  </div>

   -- more similar fields ---

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
 def create 
    @seller_profile = @seller.seller_profile.create!(seller_profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path}
    end
```

Error Message:
Started POST "/sellers/1/seller_profiles/new" for ::1 at 2021-01-11 21:37:01 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/sellers/1/seller_profiles/new"):

**UPDATED**

I changed the view to

```
<%= form_with(model: [@seller, @seller_profile], local: true) do |form| %>
--- code continues ---
```

Now the new routes work but the edit routes throws this error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `seller_profile_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000001d060
Did you mean?  seller_path):

Comment: That new error is likely related to one of the buttons that come with that view and you likely need to update the path.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a model instance instead so that your inputs are bound to the model instance. For nested resources pass an array:

```
<%= form_for([@seller, @seller_profile]) do |form| %>
```

That ensures that the inputs will contain the values entered by the user when validation fails. And it also hooks into the I18n API for translations so that it will use the translation keys for that model instead of generic keys.

If you're using Rails 5.1+ use `form_with(model: [@seller, @seller_prodile], local: true)` instead.

Comment: it works now but unfortunately on the edit route I am getting this error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `seller_profile_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000001c610>
Did you mean?  seller_path):
    1: <%= form_with(model: [@seller, @seller_profile]) do |form| %>

Comment: Thats really a follow up question - and it was good that you asked a separate question. You should consider rolling back your edit to the question as follow up questions posed as edits are not appreciated on stackoverflow as they result in a ever growing scope creep. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions