# Form displays on the new routes and gives an error on edit route [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: [@seller, @seller_profile], local: true) do |form| %>
 
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  --- similar input structure ---

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This view works well on the new route, however, on the edit route is gives this error
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `seller_profile_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000001d060
Did you mean?  seller_path):

Comment: post `routes.rb` too

Comment: Also, we'll need to see extracts from the controller, if not the entire thing.

Comment: This is a follow up question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674958/no-route-matches-post-in-rails but should be edited to include the entire context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is most likely because `@seller` is nil. Rails calls [`#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) on the array so its thus equivalent to calling `form_with(model: [@seller_profile])` which will look for the non-nested route helper.

You can solve it by setting `@seller` in the controller:

```
class SellerProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_seller

  # ...

  private

  def set_seller 
    @seller = Seller.find(params[:seller_id])
  end
end
```

Or by using [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) which avoids nesting the *member routes* (show, edit, update, destroy):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :sellers do
  resource :seller_profiles, shallow: true
end
```

```
class SellerProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_seller, only: [:new, :index, :create]

  # ...

  private

  def set_seller 
    @seller = Seller.find(params[:seller_id])
  end
end
```